# JS - Assign forEach Dom element a value in an object

Tags: javascript, css, dom, css-selectors

I'm trying to assign some CSS transfrom properties to Dom elements that are being selected through QuerySelectorAll.

Each transform property that needs to be assigned is stored in an object and the key to this property matches distinctive CSS selector,

---

To help understand , this is the redundant version of I want to achieve is:

```
  var   front = document.querySelector('.front'),
    back = document.querySelector('.back'),
    right = document.querySelector('.right'),
    left = document.querySelector('.left'),
    top = document.querySelector('.top'),
    bottom = document.querySelector('.bottom');
    // common parent class is
    boxFigure = document.querySelectorAll('.cube figure')

    front.style.transform= "rotateY(0deg) translateZ("+trans+"px)" ;
    back.style.transform= "rotateY(180deg) translateZ("+trans+"px)" ;
    left.style.transform= "rotateY(90deg) translateZ("+trans+"px)" ;
    right.style.transform= "rotateY(-90deg) translateZ("+trans+"px)" ;
    top.style.transform= "rotateX(90deg) translateZ("+trans+"px)" ;
    bottom.style.transform= "rotateX(-90deg) translateZ("+trans+"px)" ;
```

---

this is what I've tried so far:

```
var faces = {
front:"rotateY(0deg) translateZ("+trans+"px)",
back:"rotateY(180deg) translateZ("+trans+"px)" ,
left:"rotateY(90deg) translateZ("+trans+"px)" ,
right:"rotateY(-90deg) translateZ("+trans+"px)",
top:"rotateX(90deg) translateZ("+trans+"px)" ,
bottom:"rotateX(-90deg) translateZ("+trans+"px)"
};
 for (var i = 0; i < boxFigure.length; ++i){
     var side = this.className;    
    //I believe this to be wrong - elements are named like-> figure.front
     boxFigure[i].style.transform = faces[side]
};
```

I've also tried

```
function faceTrans (e){
    var side = this.className;
    boxFigure.style.transform = faces[side];
}
[].slice.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('.cube figure')).forEach(function(el){
        el.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", faceTrans, false);
    } );
```

Since I'm new to the subject I might be missing something obvious...
any suggestions are welcome.

---

HTML is

```
 <div class="cube">
            <figure class="front"> 1</figure>
            <figure class="back"> 3</figure>
            <figure class="left">2 </figure>
            <figure class="right">4 </figure>
            <figure class="top">5 </figure>
            <figure class="bottom">6 </figure>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is `boxFigure`? What is the basic markup?

Comment: it's the parent div that contains the figure.faces, I'm updating html

Comment: I'm having problems fully grasping the idea of your code. I see what you are trying to do, but it isn't clear. You have various elements. Front, back etc,. You also have boxfigures. Do you want to add the front, back etc transform styles to the boxfigures?

Comment: basically I'm building a cube

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 for (var i = 0; i < boxFigure.length; ++i){
     var side = boxFigure[i].className;    
    //I believe this to be wrong - elements are named like-> figure.front
     boxFigure[i].style.transform = faces[side];
};
```

Should do it.

Comment: Yep, it can however make you mad. Staring blindly at it for hours and hours.